# How do you setup visual studio to include the Azure name spaces?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-sdk-.net

I've installed the Azure 1.4 toolkit.  I have the new project templates in VS2010.

I want to start saving files to my azure storage account CDN via code.  I'm referencing this code snippet: http://www.totaldotnet.com/Article/ShowArticle104_AzureFileStorage.aspx

The snippet includes have:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient;
```

For the life of me I can't find the correct DLL to reference to be able to use these name spaces.

**What do I need to reference in order to access the Microsoft.WindowsAzure name space?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the article, you should find this dll in "C:\Program Files\Windows Azure SDK\v1.4\ref" folder.

BTW, What's the error message you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

You should just find Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient in the add reference dialog. Make sure you have the project set to .NET 4 and not .NET 4 Client Profile.